# Is it possible to integrate Python script inside karate tests?

Tags: python-3.x, karate

I need to test a set of APIs with Karate DSL, but inserting new set of Data is not possible from the APIs. **Is it possible to integrate a python script which will populate the DB before running the script and then similarly a script will remove that entry from the DB after the tests**